# Playing a downloaded video Error: 1, -2147483648

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

I'm trying to download a video file and then play it in an app, if I put the video file in the res folder I'm able to play it without a problem, however when I try and download the video then play it I get the VideoView Error: 1, -2147483648.

This is the code I use to download the video:

```
    try
    {

        URL url = new URL(videoURL);
        URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
        conexion.connect();

        int lengthOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
        Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Length of file: " + lengthOfFile);

        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());




        final File dir = new File(this.getFilesDir() + "/videos");
        dir.mkdirs(); //create folders where write files
        final File file = new File(dir, "my_video.mp4");

        Log.d("writePath", file.getPath());

        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        long total = 0;

        while((count = input.read(data)) != -1)
        {
            total += count;
            //publishProgress("" + (int)((total*100) / lengthOfFile));
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();

        Log.d("download", "finished");

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

        Log.d("Exception", e.getMessage());
    }
```

This appears to complete successfully, but when I try to play the file with the followed code, I get the error.

```
 // Play Video
    videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
    //

    File f = new File("/data/data/com.companyname.appname/files/videos/videoFilename.mp4");



    if(f.exists())
    {
        long len = f.length();
        String length = String.valueOf(len);
        Log.d("file", "exists");
        Log.d("length", (String)length);
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d("file", "does not exist");
    }

    //






    videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));


    videoView.setVideoPath(f.getPath());
    videoView.start();
```

As seen in the code, before playing I check if the file exists and also it's size (it is the same size as the downloaded file) but it won't play, I'm guessing the file is corrupted but I don't know why.

I have the following permissions set in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I got the exact same problem. Any answer ?

Comment: can you post your complete stacktrace? also, did you checked (like with a checksum and size or something) that your file is valid (there may be something wrong with the download part)?

Comment: Downloading a large file probably needs a more robust method, like downloading in chunks.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the error was due to the mediaplayer not having file permissions on the locally stored video. Try storing the video onto the external storage.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me once, the problem was with permissions.
What you have to do when downloading a file, you have to give it read/ write permissions.
So after downloading the file, add these lines and try :

```
                            file.setExecutable(true, false);
                            file.setReadable(true, false);
                            file.setWritable(true, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just one question, why don't you pass the URL to the video directly to the VideoView ?
Normally all the examples you see on the web do this:

```
VideoView video = new VideoView(mContext);
video.setMediaController(new MediaController(mContext));
video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(this.url));
```

Where "mContext" in your application context and "this.url" is the URL you need to load in the VideoView.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it this is a permissions issue. The file needs to be world readable, but I assume you don't want to force the user to root his/her phone to be able to run the proper linux command.

That leaves you with two options:

1. Since the application owns the file, you can use a FileDescriptor to open the file

   FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("/data/data/com.mypackage/myfile");
   mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fileInputStream.getFD());

   But since you arnr't using a MediaPlayer, I guess that is not an option.
2. Set the permission when getting the file.

   String basedir = ("/data/data/com.companyname.appname/files/videos/videoFilename.mp4");
   File file = this.ctx.getDir(basedir, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

Hope it helps! Cheers.